# Ionic 5: Update an array of objects from multiple componentes

Tags: javascript, angular, ionic-framework, rxjs, ionic5

I am bulding an ionic 5 app at the moment and I am standing in front of a problem. At start of the application I am creating an array of objects. I need to store this array in someway, so that i have the following functionality:

- Visualize the objects on an component which updates automatically(in multiple components at the same time)
- Trigger function of the objects, which change their values/properties. These changes should automatically be updated in the array (from multiple components

I looked into Observable but i struggle at implementing the usage of the functions of the objects. As a side note i am not able to pass the array as an input of the components.

Appreciate some tips from you.

Some code examples:

item.ts

```js
export class Item {
 private name;

 constructor(n: String) {
  this.name = n;
 }

 getName() {
  return this.name;
 }

 setName(value: String) {
  this.name = value;
 }
}
```

app.component.ts

```js
[...]
private items: Item[];

 constructor() {
  this.initArray();
 }

 initArray() {
  this.items = [new Item("hi"), new Item("world")];
 }
```

display.component.html

```html
<ion-list>
  <ion-item *ng-For="let item of items">
   {{item.getName()}}
   <ion-button (click)="item.setName("New")>Change<ion-button>
  </ion-item>
</ion-list>
```

someService.service.ts

```js
export class SomeService {
 constructor () {}

 updateItems() {
  items.foreach(e => {
   e.setName(e.getName() + "1");
  }
 }
}
```

This would be a basic demo of what i need. i am searching a way to give the array to all these diffrent position and keep them updated everywhere no matter which side makes a change.

Comment: Sharing some code and showing use where you had problems would help us to answer this question.

Comment: Added a basic example. Sorry my bad